# web link doesn't load outside the main window

Tags: xml, url, browser, asp.net-web-api

I need to use the APIs in these samples:

http://xml.fxstreet.com/ecopro/data/samples.htm

when I open any of them by clicking or opening in a new window they work.
They even work when I open them from the "view source" of the link I posted, so there is no collateral javascript/css code needed. And it let's me do it as many times as I want

But when I copy and paste the link of a sample in any browser I get empty result.

I also get empty result when I download a link to a String in c#:

```
String res = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://xml.fxstreet.com/ecopro/data/data.aspx?view=day&format=xml&key=ff969c0f-709e-4086-afb3-d2afe1e9665f");
```

I don't understand why....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts to work, when the GET request is made with a Referer (tested in Firefox). So i would suggest to modify your code a bit and fake a referer.
I guess, the API is in a transition phase or something, where they fade out old URLs and switch to client_key/token approach.

Give this a try (untested):

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

client.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://xml.fxstreet.com/ecopro/data/samples.htm");
client.Headers.Add("Cache", "no-cache");

String res = client.DownloadString("http://xml.fxstreet.com/ecopro/data/data.aspx?view=day&format=xml&key=ff969c0f-709e-4086-afb3-d2afe1e9665f");
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Now it works with the referrer